# get JSON object with API client

Tags: java, android, json

Im trying to get JSONobject from api but i cant get this piece of code to work. 
I am new to android and java and JSON. i keep getting the error: in JSONobject cannot be applied

Main code:

```
try {
        APIClientJSONObject api = new APIClientJSONObject();
        JSONObject result = null;

        try {
            result = api.execute(URL).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<CustomListView> contents = new ArrayList<CustomListView>();

            try {
                JSONObject row = result.getJSONObject(result**ERROR HERE**);

                String content = row.optString("FormattedName");
                String content2 = row.optString("Title");
                String content3 = row.optString("Subtitle");
                String content4 = row.optString("Text");

                EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInternNaam);
                name.setText(content);
                EditText titel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
                titel.setText(content2);
                EditText ondertitel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOndertitel);
                ondertitel.setText(content3);
                EditText EditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTekst);
                EditText.setText(Html.fromHtml(content4));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Api client:

```
public class APIClientJSONObject extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>             {

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

    JSONObject result = null;

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(params[0]));
        InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        result = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

JSON output:

```
{
  "FormattedName": "Home page | Footer grijs",
  "Title": null,
  "Subtitle": null,
  "Text": "<div style=\"text-align: center;\"><img style=\"max-width: 80%;\" src=\"/MoxieManager/code.PNG\" alt=\"\"></div>",
  "WebsiteId": "6869a7a1-0d65-4cfa-9df1-b0b0d346212e",
  "Id": "b9906cb0-cdb2-484a-b603-020e8b64f97b",
  "DateCreated": "2016-01-25T12:09:50.367",
  "DateModified": "2016-02-11T08:51:54.223",
  "CreatedBy": "Drie-O Automatisering",
  "ModifiedBy": "Drie-O Automatisering",
  "SortOrder": 0
}
```

Comment: Is the error coming at this line?JSONObject row = result.getJSONObject(result);

Comment: Yes, sorry i didnt point that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason:**

You are already getting the `JSONObject` from `AsycnTask`. There is no need of

```
JSONObject row = result.getJSONObject(result);
```

When you try to used this it means you are trying to find a object result inside object result. Which is not the case here.

**Solution:**

You should remove the above mentioned call and use `result` in these calls like below.

```
String content = result.optString("FormattedName");
String content2 = result.optString("Title");
String content3 = result.optString("Subtitle");
String content4 = result.optString("Text");
```

Comment: Perfect. Glad I could help.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the error coming at this line?

```
JSONObject row = result.getJSONObject(result);
```

result is a JSONObject, and the method requires a String.

Why not try to convert result to String and pass it. Something like.

```
JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject();
   result.toString();
 JSONObject row = result.getJSONObject(resultJson );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already got the JSON output as given from the APIClient.

```
JSONObject row = result.getJSONObject(result);
```

this line is redundant unless your real response is an array list enclosed object and you are getting only a row from it.

Directly you can access internal elements in main object now.